# How to show instantly show data after form submit via ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

How to show instantly data after form submit via ajax after saving this one. After saving this via my controller function ,how to view saved data into same page without refreshing page:-

```html
<span class=" store_comment_like " data-comment-id="{{ $comment->id }}"  >  </span>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.post-comment').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var commentId = $(this).attr('data-comment-id');
      var data= {
        commentId:commentId,
        method:'POST',
      }
      $.ajax({
        url:'/schooldukan/post/comment/'+commentId,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
          printSuccessMsg(data.success);
          $('#commentonpost2')[0].reset();
        } else {
          printErrorMsg(data.error);
        }
     } 
  
  });
```

Comment: use jquery append(https://api.jquery.com/append/) to add new comment in DOM after successfully submit.

Comment: This question has most certainly been answered many many times here. This seems like a "code for me" question.

Comment: can you please me the links

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy. You can append your data after an action. Use `append()` with your dom wrapper element.

For example, if you want to show saved data after success operation, try this;

```
success: function(data) {
 $("#wrapperHtmlTag").append("<span>" + YOUR_DATA + "</span>");
}
```

As you know, you should have a wrapper to append your data like;

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page title</title>
</head>
<body>
...
...
<div id="wrapperHtmlTag"></div>
...
...
</body>
</html>
```

So `div#wrapperHtmlTag` will be filled with your data.

Comment: can you tell me the data that i had saved now , how can i show that with its id ..